# Java - How to get only message body from FileDescriptorProto

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protocols

I am trying to print contents of message body of proto file. But my code below is printing details of import too which I don't want. Any suggestion on how to filter this so that only message contents will be printed.

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("mymessages.desc");
Descriptors.FileDescriptorSet set = Descriptors.FileDescriptorSet.parseFrom(fin);
for(FileDescriptorProto fileDesc : set.getFileList()){
    List<DescriptorProto> descList = fileDesc.getMessageTypeList();
         for(DescriptorProto desc : descList ){
            System.out.Println(desc) ; // print all proto info including the imported field as well as message 
    }
  }
}
```

My proto file

```
syntax = "proto3"

import "validate.proto";

message User{
  string firstName = 1;
  string lastName = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just delete the header lines:

```
System.out.println(desc.replaceAll("(?sm)\\A.*?(?=^message)", ""));
```

The regex `(?sm)\\A.*?(?=^message)` matches everything from start up to, but not including, the first line that starts with `message`, which is replaced with a blank (ie deleted).